# Будет ли киносайт в домене .art оптимизироваться для поисковиков?

Tags: seo, домен, веб-сайт

Дело в том что мне очень понравилось этот домен, и хочу узнать будет ли оптимизироваться этот домен для поисковиков.
Сайт будет работать на платформе ASP.NET core, для просмотра различного рода медиа.

Comment: поисковикам вроде как всё равно какой домен. главное как ты сам его продвигаешь

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле это хороший вопрос с точки зрения SEO.

И с точки зрения SEO нужно сперва ответить на другой вопрос, а именно "как работает поиск сайтов в Google или Yandex?"

Для примера расскажу про Google, у Yandex всё аналогично, но у Yandex эти обновления были гораздо позже (2018 - 2022 год).

Ранее на позицию сайта влияли многие факторы, начиная с домена и имени сайта и заканчивая `html` мета-тегами.

Что это сулило? Сайт с названием `купить-авто-онлайн.рф` чаще попадал в топ-10 по запросу "купить авто онлайн", хотя на самом деле этот сайт мог никак не относится к автомобилям и их продажам. Не скажу точно, но в районе 2014 года для Google и в 2016 году для Yandex название сайта перестало играть столь значимую роль, Google в это время начал активно смотреть на сам контент сайта без использования `html` тегов `keyworld` и `description`, Yandex поступил так же, но намного позже.

Соответственно вывод и ответ на ваш вопрос. На данный момент название сайта и его домен не играют никакой роли для Google и Yandex, даже не влияют `keyword` и `description` страниц, так как поисковики смотрят на сам контент сайта, а чтобы поисковик видел контент правильно у вас должны быть валидные HTML теги, то есть правильное использование таких тегов как `p`, `h1-h6`, `strong` и т.д - именно на них смотрят поисковые машины, Google же в свою очередь умеет смотреть и JS сайты без `ssr`, когда у вас на сайте присутствует всего один `div`, который после подхватывает `vue` или `react`.